# How can I change the default loading tile color in LeafletJS?

Tags: javascript, css, maps, leaflet, geomap

By default, when leafletJS is loading a map, the background tiles are all grey. I'd like to change that color to be black (or any other arbitrary color). How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's controlled by the below css rule in the file 'leaflet.css':

```
.leaflet-container {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

so you just need to change this rule.

Comment: This isn't working for me, mid 2019. The property is set, and overwriting the underlying property, but the map still flashes the default grey when loading.

Comment: Make sure to load your style sheet after the leaflet style sheet or append the rule with !important

Comment: This can also be done with `!important` without worrying about its ordering with respect to the leaflet style sheet.