# How to change background of Leaflet map in RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm creating a Shiny App using a leaflet widget. My map has a simple Shapefile with no basemap engaged. Leaflet renders a default grey background. I would like to change the background to white.

I see some answers using javascript code, but I am unfamiliar how to implement this in the R language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the Leaflet default background color with CSS, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13852053/1781026).

You can use custom CSS in your Shiny app by adding it into the HTML head of the Shiny output:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".leaflet-container { background: #f00; }"))
  ),
  # etc.
)
# etc.
```

Other possibilites for adding styles, for example with external CSS files, are explained in the [Shiny documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).