# Map background colour/transparency within R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson, r-leaflet

I'm using a geojson file to produce a map with leaflet on R. I would like to change **the background colour** to the white, or make the background transparent if it is possible (this is actually really desired one). I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851888/how-can-i-change-the-default-loading-tile-color-in-leafletjs/13852053#13852053) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443622/how-to-change-background-of-leaflet-map-in-rstudio). I am able to change the border colour and filled colour but cannot change the colour of the outside of map > background colour.

```
wLeaf <- leaflet(states) %>%
  addProviderTiles("MapBox", options = providerTileOptions(
    id = "mapbox.light",
    accessToken = Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')))%>%
    addPolygons(
      weight = 2,
      opacity = 1,
      color = "#222",
      fillColor = "gray",
    )
```

How can I handle the colour or transparency issue of background for the map?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set you basemap totally transparent i.e. `opacity = 0` under providerTileOptions?

Answer (score 2):

in case it helps, first create the background call

```
backg <- htmltools::tags$style(".leaflet-container { background: tomato; }" )
```

Then you can add this object as CSS format to your map

```
sts <- tigris::states(cb = TRUE) # you map
leaflet::leaflet(data = sts) %>% 
addPolygons(fillColor = "grey90", stroke = FALSE) %>%
htmlwidgets::prependContent(backg) #this applies the CSS format
```

All together:

```
library(dplyr)
backg <- htmltools::tags$style(".leaflet-container { background: tomato; }" )  
sts <- tigris::states(cb = TRUE)
leaflet::leaflet(data = sts) %>% 
addPolygons(fillColor = "grey90", stroke = FALSE) %>%
htmlwidgets::prependContent(backg)
```

[image: Result with tomato background color]

Cheers!