# How to change color of leaflet map around the polygon shape in r?

Tags: css, r, leaflet, r-markdown, r-leaflet

I am using a **shape file** in **leaflet plot** & would like to have `white` color space external to the outer boundary of **polygon shape** instead of default **greyish color** background like color but unable to do so.

[image]

**tried with:** `leaflet(options = leafletOptions(style = list("background-color" = "white")))`

**complete code:**

```
ind_states %>% leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE,
                                                dragging = FALSE,
                                                minZoom = 3,
                                                style = list(
                                                  "background-color" = "white"
                                                )
                                                )) %>%
          
          addPolygons(
                      label = label_daily,
                      labelOptions = labelOptions(
                        opacity = .6,
                        style = list(
                            "color" = "white",
                            "background-color" = "black",
                            "font-size" = "15px",
                            "border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                        )
                      ),
                      stroke = TRUE,
                      color = "white",
                      dashArray = "3",
                      weight = .2,
                      smoothFactor = .5,
                      opacity = 1,
                      fillOpacity = 0.5,
                      fillColor = ~ pal_daily(Daily_confirmed),
                      highlightOptions = highlightOptions(weight = .5,
                                                          fillOpacity = 1,
                                                          bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%

          addLegend(position = "bottomleft",
                    pal = pal_daily,
                    values = ~ ind_states$Daily_confirmed,
                    title = "Daily Confirmed Cases",
                    opacity = 0.7)
```

Also tried by adding: `addTiles(fill = "white") %>%` & `addTiles(fillColor = "white") %>%` but got error.

**Desired result example with some random image:**
(choropleth map with external white space)

[image]

Would appreciate any help !!

---

**UPDATE**

from SO post: [blank, white background for leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989920/blank-white-background-for-leaflet-map)

As per above link I saved my plot as R object: `daily_leaflet_plt` & ran below code but thats not working. **I am not sure how to change css for this in rmarkdown**

````
```{r results="daily_leaflet_plt"}
cat("
<style>
.leaflet-container {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
")
```
````

Comment: Have you tried stroke = TRUE & color = 'white' in addPolygons()?

Comment: @SusanSwitzer stroke & color = "white" is coloring the border into white whereas I am looking for external grey background space to be colored as white.

Comment: As this issue is more relevant to css & it was answered in another SO post so closing this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767588/how-to-change-css-in-rmarkdown-cell-shiny/